# en java obtener Token de una API mediante POST con las credenciales en el cuerpo y un header

Tags: java, post, jsonobject

En java netbeans, Necesito obtener un Bearer Token mediante el metodo POST en el que debo enviar 3 credenciales en el cuerpo de la petición (client_id = "cbb998nbhgn", client_secret= "123456" y grant_type="Client_masther") y el header poner "Server_client:roax_client"

Pude hacerlo en VisualFoxPro, pero ahora tengo que hacerlo en java y no avanzo.

En Postman obtengo token

```
{
    "access_token": "BamzzzmbtL9svua5L2I3rVbc",
    "expires_in": 6000,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "read write"
}
```

Solo Llego hasta aqui.

```
        JSONObject oJson = new JSONObject();
        oJson.put("documento_identidad", jtfDNI_agente.getText()); // se obtiene de un jtextField
        oJson.put("genero", sexo);  // // se obtiene de un RadioButton (m o f)
        String salida = "";

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        URL url = new URL("https://xroad-sitio.com/r1/catamarca/GOB/400033/OBTENER_DATOS_PERSONA");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");                     
        
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");            
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "Server_client:roax_client");

        String client_id = "cbb998nbhgn";
        String client_secret = "123456";
        String grant_type = "Client_masther";

        connection.setRequestProperty("body", "client_id= " + client_id);
        connection.setRequestProperty("body", "client_secret= " + client_secret);
        connection.setRequestProperty("body", "grant_type= " + grant_type);
        connection.connect();
        if(connection.getResponseCode() != 200){
           // aqui me retorna 500
        }else{
           System.out.println("ok")
           // leer el json para obtener el Token
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba con la Clase `HttpsURLConnection`, ya que estas usando la Http normal y la url es https. Saludos